# Html5 media capture limit the length of the video?

Tags: html

I am using the new Html5 media capture api to capture video on the iphone. I have a requirement to limit the video recording to a specific length e.g. 6 seconds.

The html that I am using is:

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="fileupload" accept="video/*" capture="camera">
```

Is it possible to limit the length of the recording using Html5?

Comment: are the videos already recorded?

Comment: No. With the above line of html the camera can be launched and the video recorded...

Comment: you're gonna have to do some digging. check out the w3c's dap api....but even if getRequestedMedia is in place, idk any browsers that support it. can you use iOS or are you only writing this in HTML5?

Comment: Ideally we want to target any mobile or mainly iOS and Android.

Comment: well you can certainly do it in iOS...check out iOS developer library; actually your best bet for both is most likely phonegap. you should dig into that

Comment: Ok. But with phonegap are you able to visit the website in the browser or do you have to download the app? I am trying to avoid having to download the app.

Comment: ah....idk exactly, but if you can't you could just use cordova http://cordova.apache.org/

Comment: You might want to use just `camera` instead of `capture="camera"` as recommended in the [HTML Media Capture drafts](https://addpipe.com/blog/correct-syntax-html-media-capture/) since 2012.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible (yet).

The latest [HTML Media Capture](https://w3c.github.io/html-media-capture/) (5 July 2016) draft does not mention any *limit* type of attribute for the `input` HTML element.

I've put together a [list of all the HTML Media Capture drafts](https://addpipe.com/blog/correct-syntax-html-media-capture/).